# Timeout Settings for R Shiny on Cloud Foundry

Tags: r, shiny, cloud-foundry

How do you change timeout settings for R Shiny app on Cloud Foundry so that app doesn't gray out after the default 1 minute?

Comment: What do you mean by "gray out"?  Also, which timeout are you referring to?  The timeout for your application to start, which defaults to 60s?

Comment: I believe it's the app session timeout, used to disconnect a session if the user is idle (default 60s).